# After converting to dto child set order jumbles up

Tags: mapstruct

After converting to dto using mapstruct, child id order jumbles up.
If i return just the entity without converting to dto the child is properly ordered

"data":[
{
"personName":"TestUser",
"cars":[
{
"id":"2021-000001"
},
{
"id":"2021-000003"
},
{
"id":"2021-000002"
},
{
"id":"2021-000004"
}
}
]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the order is different is due to the fact that MapStruct used a `HashSet` by default when mapping into a `Set`.

The current implementation types for MapStruct are the following:

| Interface type | Implementation type |
| --- | --- |
| `Iterable` | `ArrayList` |
| `Collection` | `ArrayList` |
| `List` | `ArrayList` |
| `Set` | `HashSet` |
| `SortedSet` | `TreeSet` |
| `NavigableSet` | `TreeSet` |
| `Map` | `HashMap` |
| `SortedMap` | `TreeMap` |
| `NavigableMap` | `TreeMap` |
| `ConcurrentMap` | `ConcurrentHashMap` |
| `ConcurrentNavigableMap` | `ConcurrentSkipListMap` |

This can be seen in [Implementation types used for collection mappings](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#implementation-types-for-collection-mappings)

There is currently a [feature request](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2303) to change this into an order preserving set / map and it will be included in 1.5.

At the moment you can fix this by using an `@ObjectFactory` that will return a `LinkedHashSet`